# Using eventReactive and inputMatrix requires button to be pressed twice

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a Shiny app and want to have the user be able to enter data into a matrix that automatically grows in size as more data is entered. And when an action button is pressed, a calculation is to be performed on the inputted data. As such `matrixInput` (from the shinyMatrix package) together with `eventReactive` looked like it was what I was looking for.

However, what I found is that if the user enters data and then presses the action button without first clicking outside of the data entry area, the function does not register that the data has been updated. However, if the button is pressed twice, then the results are correct. I am assuming that the input has not been updated when the action button is pressed, and that as such the calculation is performed on the previous data.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

A replicable example is presented below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

initVals <- matrix(round(runif(12, 10, 100)), 2, 2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(matrixInput(
      inputId = "sample",
      value = initVals,
      class = "numeric",
      rows = list(extend = TRUE),
      cols = list(extend = TRUE)
    ),
    actionButton("run", "Calculate sum")
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("Sum"))
  )
) 


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  sumcalc <- eventReactive(input$run, {
    sum(input$sample, na.rm=TRUE)
  })
  
  output$Sum <- renderTable({
    sumcalc()
  }) 
  
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, `observeEvent` is more appropriate in this case.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

initVals <- matrix(round(runif(12, 10, 100)), 2, 2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(matrixInput(
      inputId = "sample",
      value = initVals,
      class = "numeric",
      rows = list(extend = TRUE),
      cols = list(extend = TRUE)
    ),
    actionButton("run", "Calculate sum")
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("Sum"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$run, {

    sumcalc <- reactive({
      sum(isolate(input$sample), na.rm=TRUE)
    })

    output$Sum <- renderTable({
      sumcalc()
    })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, that worked wonders. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think I replied a bit too quickly. What happens now is that the calculation is automatically done, even without pressing the button. I still want the user to have to press the button for the sum to be calculated.

Comment: @Phil, use of `isolate()` should help with that.  Please try the updated code.

Comment: Still doesn't work as intended. If I click out of a cell in the matrix before I press the button, it updates. But if I press the button before "leaving" the matrix cell, the calculation is not performed.

Comment: It works for me most of the time. However, sometimes if you press the button before "leaving" the matrix cell, the calculation is not performed after first click.  It does perform the calculation after second click.  That is strange.

Comment: Yeah, that is the same problem that I've encountered and the reason for this post. It's like the information isn't loaded into the matrix until we leave the input area.